# How to create ASP.NET user control with inner properties used with markup similar to UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I am creating a user control that I wish to have inner properties as well as normal attributes.  Although the actual function of the control has nothing to do with, say, UpdatePanel, I am trying to create something with similar ASPX markup.  The developer designing the page should be able to use my control like:

```
<ns:MyControl ID="someID" runat="server" SomeOtherAttribute="true">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="someLabel" runat="server" Text="Normal page markup and controls should go here" /><br />
    <p>This should be OK too.</p>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <ControlEvent ControlName="idOfOtherControl" Event="Click" />
  <ControlEvent ControlName="idOfSomeOtherControl" Event="MouseOver" />
</ns:MyControl>
```

Also acceptable would be wrapping the `ControlEvent` tags in some other tag, more like what happens when using UpdatePanel:

```
<ns:MyControl ID="someID" runat="server" SomeOtherAttribute="true">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="someLabel" runat="server" Text="Normal page markup and controls should go here" /><br />
    <p>This should be OK too.</p>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <ControlEvents>
    <ns:ControlEvent ControlName="idOfOtherControl" Event="Click" />
    <ns:ControlEvent ControlName="idOfSomeOtherControl" Event="MouseOver" />
  </ControlEvents>
</ns:MyControl>
```

But, the `ControlEvents` tag should only allow this one particular tag, not normal server markup or anything.

I understand how to get the content inside `ContentTemplate` to render (in my `Page_Init`, I use the `ITemplate.InstantiateIn(placeholderControl)` method).  That part works fine.  Where I'm having trouble is getting the `ControlEvent` part to work.  I can create the inner property in the code-behind like:

```
[TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Multiple)]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[TemplateContainer(typeof(ControlEvent))]
public List<ControlEvent> ControlEvents { get; set; }
```

In so doing, ASP.NET does seem to understand that I want a `ControlEvents` tag.  But, I can't get properties, either inner properties or attributes, to be recognized.  Instead, if I try the first type of markup, I get a runtime Parser Error: "Property 'ControlEvents' does not have a property named 'ControlName'."  If I try the second type of markup, I get a `NullReferenceException` as a parser error at runtime, with the error being generated at the `<ns:ControlEvent>` line.

I've checked online, but I haven't found a good example or explanation of how to accomplish what I am trying to do with `ControlEvent` or `ControlEvents`.  What am I missing?  Could someone point me to a good example here?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

It turned out that some of the problem was due to how I had the control registered to the page using it.  If I was using:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/MyControl.ascx" TagPrefix="ns" TagName="MyControl" %>
```

It appeared that the control itself was recognized in the markup, but `ns:ControlEvent` was not.  If I changed the `Register` to:

```
<%@ Register Namespace="Namespace.Controls" TagPrefix="ns" Assembly="MyAssembly" %>
```

it worked as far as understanding the control itself (provided that `runat="server"` was included in the `ns:ControlEvent` tags).  However, the child controls of MyControl were not being instantiated or rendered anymore, and events of the control such as `Page_Init` and `Page_Load` were not firing.

After much messing around, I figured out that I seem to need both `Register` directives.  This seems like a messy "solution," and it doesn't really even solve everything, as (for not) at least some of the markup in my control is not rendering, though the template control (`ContentTemplate`) seems to be working again.

What kinds of things could I be missing here that would make this control less messy to use and that would make this control actually render everything correctly?

Comment: You can register the controls in `Web.config` so that they apply globally to all pages in your application, rather than having to include them in every page.

Comment: @batwad True, and I'll have to give that a try.  I was hoping not to have to do that though, mostly due to organizational code standards and conventions.  Besides, I know that UpdatePanel and the like are "built-in," but for user template controls, is having to include in the Web.config or twice in the page really the norm in ASP.NET 3.5?

Answer (score 10):

The properties must be implmented as a `Collection` and not a `List`; other than that, the most important thing to remember here is that the parent control must have **`[ParseChildren(true)]`** attribute set for this to work, otherwise the collection will be `null`.

The following (server-control) sample works as expected:

```
   public class ControlEvent
    {
        public string ControlName { get; set; }
        public string Event { get; set; }
    }

    [ParseChildren(true)]
    public class SampleControl : System.Web.UI.Control, INamingContainer
    {
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        [TemplateContainer(typeof(SampleControl))]
        public ITemplate ContentTemplate { get; set; }

        [MergableProperty(false), PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty), DefaultValue((string)null)]
        public Collection<ControlEvent> ControlEvents { get; set; }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();

            if (ContentTemplate != null)
                ContentTemplate.InstantiateIn(this);

            if (null != ControlEvents)
                foreach (ControlEvent e in ControlEvents)
                    Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = string.Format("ControlName:{0}, Event:{1}", e.ControlName, e.Event) });
        }
    }
```

HTH.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, anyway.  Thanks!  I already had ParseChildren(true).  I found that the problem ended up being in how I had the control registered in the page.  See the edit to my question (coming shortly).